# Keycloak : Client not found exception?

Tags: keycloak

I setup Keycloak server and everything run fine in server machine,But when i tried to integrate Keycloak with local machine(localhost) i am getting

> We're sorry ... Client not found.

[image]

Even i check my local machine ip address and added in `Keycloak->Clients->Settings->Valid Redirect URIs` even then i am getting same exception.

Answer (score 14):

The error message indicates that the client ID and the realm of your client application don't match the configured clients on the Keycloak server.

Please check the exact (case-sensitive) spelling. *Client ID* (in *Keycloak -> Clients -> Settings*) need to match *resource* on your client and the *Name* (in *Realm Settings -> General*) needs to match *realm* on your client.

You can also go the *Client -> Installation -> Format JSON* and look at the JSON configuration. I reduced it to the two relevant entries.

```
{
  "realm": "...",
  "resource": "...",
  ...
}
```

Comment: apart from this can you reply one question can we used keyclock with localhost also without ip address?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi - please don't raise questions in comments. Your questions is very short and doesn't provide enough context. Please open a new question or contact me directly.

Comment: In the configuration JSON indicated by @ahus1, you can include "resource", to identify the application, like "resource" : "js-application".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - In my case keycloak was configured to have a different `authBaseUrl` so the keycloak url was:

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/master/...
```

instead  of

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/...
```

I fixed that on the client side.