# Why won't the Keycloak with Spring Boot tutorial work?

Tags: keycloak

I've been trying to follow [the Keycloak tutorial from DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-k) (EDIT: which seems to be a nearly verbatim repost from [the tutorial on the official Keycloak blog](https://blog.keycloak.org/2017/05/easily-secure-your-spring-boot.html), apparently by the same author), but I've run into the following problems:

- `index.html` not being found
- when clicking on the link to the interior page, the error

  > **We're sorry...**
  >
  > Page not found
- on that same page, the error

  > javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [products]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/products] again.
- the Keycloak admin panel appearing instead of the sample app

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of subtle but significant inconsistencies/typos in that tutorial. In order of appearance:

## Main tutorial

1. the location of `index.html` is given as `/src/resources/static`. If you are using Spring Initializr, the pre-made code will have both `main` and `test` directories under `src`, so the correct location will instead be `src/main/resources/static`.
2. In the code for the controller, line 9 is

   ```
   return "products";
   ```

   This tells Spring to use `products.html`. The actual HTML file will be `product`, singular, because it is generated from `product.ftl`. Take the 's' off of the return value.
3. In the `application.properties` file, one of the lines given is

   ```
   keycloak.realm=springboot
   ```

   Earlier, when in the Keycloak admin panel, the guide suggested naming the realm "SpringBoot". These values need to match, and [they are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43967299/). Change either one.
4. After setup is complete, the instructions say

   > Now browse to “http://localhost:8080”

   The correct URL is `http://localhost:8081`, since `server.port` was set to 8081 in `application.properties`. Port 8080 should still be in use by the admin console.

With these changes, the test app should load and behave as described.

## Adding Spring Security

Be careful not to reintroduce the `products`/`product` typo when copying in the new `getProducts()` method.

Comment: Thank you sir! The published tutorial has so many mistakes and it is really hard to follow it and do something successfully. You saved my day. Wish that the article was updates or removed.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, to make the official documentation work, you can use the answer from SOLO and complement with the following code:

**Add keycloak to POM**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Add dependency management to POM**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**Change .ftl format to .ftlh and use like this:**

```
<html>
<h2>My products</h2>
<ul>
    <#list products as product>
        <li>${product}</li>
    </#list>
</ul>
<p>
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
</p>
```